# Proving the convergence/divergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos\ n}{n} (1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, fourier-series

Do the following series converges? Why?

$$ \sum_{n=1}^ \infty  \frac{\cos\ n}{n} (1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$$

Comment: After 4 questions closed on 4 asked (this is number 5), you might want to start to worry about the discrepancy between what you post on the site and what is considered acceptable here. No?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. One may apply [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test).

One may prove that,
$$
n \mapsto \frac1{n} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)
$$ is decreasing to $0$. Then use the fact that
$$
\left|\sum_{k=1}^n \cos k\right|=\left|\Re \sum_{k=1}^n e^{ik}\right|=\left|\Re \frac{e^{i}\left(e^{in}-1\right)}{e^{i}-1}\right|\leq \frac2{1-\cos(1)}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\frac{1}{1}+\cdots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=S_n$. If we can show that the sequence $\frac{S_n}{n}$ is decreasing towards $0$ then we are done, by the [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test), since $M_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \cos n$ is bounded. We can proceed directly,

$nS_{n+1}-(n+1)S_n=nS_{n} + \frac{n}{\sqrt{n+1}} - (n+1)S_n = \frac{n}{\sqrt{n+1}} - S_n<0$.